# Dealing with a reverse proxy in an Angular app that uses socket.io

Tags: angular, socket.io

I have an Angular application that communicates with a Node backend running at localhost:3000 and I'd like to configure a reverse proxy so the requests to the backend are '/api/user/login' instead of 'http://localhost:3000/user/login'. I've googled a bit and it's really easy to do using builtin Angular CLI proxy capabilities. My problem is that the application also uses socket.io and I couldn't manage to find a way to make it work after setting up the proxy. I've created a `proxy.conf.json` file with the following content:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  },
  "/socket.io": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

The requests to the backend work perfectly, but I've got an error regarding socket.io connection:

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://localhost:4200/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=h592dAWowJvCLxO5AAAC'
>   failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out

What do I need to change to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just by chance, I found this issue in github:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6081

As it says, there's a couple of options, `ws` and `wss`, to proxy websocket connections, so I modified the proxy settings file:

```
"/socket.io": {
  "target": "http://localhost:3000",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "ws": true
}
```

Now, everything works as before adding the proxy.

The strange thing is that I didn't find anything about this option in the Angular documentation (https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server). I've also checked webpack website looking for its server's proxy options but I couldn't find anything relevant. I'd like to have a list of all the available options, does anyone know where to get it?

**Edit**
It seems that Angular uses `node-http-proxy` for its development server, so here are the options:

https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy#options

Cheers,